# Filter on boolean field increases latency and CPU

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, booleanquery, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm using the AWS ElasticSearch service (1.5.2) and is receiving more than 100 requests/sec without problems.

Almost every query have geo filters, full text filters, integer filters...
But I have a problem, adding one simple filter more; a boolean term filter.

```js
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_all" : { }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "and" : {
          "filters" : [ {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [ {
                "terms" : {
                  "my_boolean_field" : [ false ]
                }
              }, 
              {
                "range" : {
                  "_timestamp" : {
                    "from" : null,
                    "to" : "2016-05-04T15:12:00Z",
                    "include_lower" : true,
                    "include_upper" : false
                  }
                }
              } ]
            }
          }, {
            "geo_distance" : {
              "rounded_location" : [ -8.42, 42.24 ],
              "distance" : "300000m",
              "distance_type" : "plane",
              "optimize_bbox" : "indexed"
            }
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort" : [ {
    "_geo_distance" : {
      "rounded_location" : [ {
        "lat" : 42.24,
        "lon" : -8.42
      } ],
      "unit" : "m"
    }
  }, {
    "date" : {
      "order" : "desc"
    }
  }, {
    "price" : {
      "order" : "asc"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Once the boolean filter is added, CPU in all nodes of ElasticSearch increases from 10 to 30% and during 10-15 minutes the average latency increases from 20 to 400ms, after a while latencies go back to normal numbers but CPU doesn't.

That boolean field is mapped properly and is searchable... has anyone a hint about this issue? (Query is formed with "terms" instead of "term" due to the official Java library that I'm using).

Comment: Can you try the same query, but swap positions between the `terms` boolean filter and the `range` one in the `must` clause?

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried that, and also I tried to put the boolean   out of the boolean section, at same level of the geo_location filter... And result was more or less the same.

Comment: Any memory (heap) pressure during these high latency periods? Increased number and/or duration for the old GCs?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I couldn't solve the issue performing the query like I described here...

I solved this creating **2 different document types**, according to the TRUE/FALSE value of the related field.

With this approach, no CPU increase, no latency problems... And since ElasticSearch can search in multiple document types at a time, this separation wasn't cause major problems to my application code ;)

So now, I perform the same query in both cases but changing only the document type target:

```
POST /my_index/doc_type_with_true_value/_search
POST /my_index/doc_type_with_false_value/_search
```

```js
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_all" : { }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "and" : {
          "filters" : [ {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [ {
                "range" : {
                  "_timestamp" : {
                    "from" : null,
                    "to" : "2016-05-04T15:12:00Z",
                    "include_lower" : true,
                    "include_upper" : false
                  }
                }
              } ]
            }
          }, {
            "geo_distance" : {
              "rounded_location" : [ -8.42, 42.24 ],
              "distance" : "300000m",
              "distance_type" : "plane",
              "optimize_bbox" : "indexed"
            }
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort" : [ {
    "_geo_distance" : {
      "rounded_location" : [ {
        "lat" : 42.24,
        "lon" : -8.42
      } ],
      "unit" : "m"
    }
  }, {
    "date" : {
      "order" : "desc"
    }
  }, {
    "price" : {
      "order" : "asc"
    }
  } ]
}
```